# Discord Bot - AsyncIO - Cannot close a running event loop

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-10, discord, chatbot

newbie here.

Trying to get my discord bot online but keep hitting this error: `raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")` when I run `discord.Client().run`

Did anyone have this issue?

Here's my code:

```
import discord
discord.Client().run('DISCORD_TOKEN')
```

Tried nest_asyncio, did not work. Tried on Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 - no luck. This was run on Anaconda, Windows 10.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!